# How can I set policies in VSTS 2017 for all project team members

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc, checkin-policy

I found info to set a policy such as check in on each computer in Visual Studio but I am hoping to set it in VSTS 2017 for all project team members.

Is there such a way?

Comment: For future reference: "VSTS 2017" is not an accurate product title. There is Visual Studio Team Services, which has no meaningfully displayed version number, and TFS 2017. This will result in confusion if you ask a question that is specific to one platform or another.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about [TFVC check-in policies](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/add-check-policies).

For policies to work, the associated policy assembly has to be installed for each user on their local PC. There is no way around this.

Policies only apply **within Visual Studio**. There is nothing preventing someone from bypassing the policy entirely by removing the assembly from their computer, by using the editor in the web portal, or by directly interacting with source control via code or the TF.exe command line utility.

Comment: This seems like a major step back, in the on premises version of TFS 2017 you could set a policy centrally that all users would have to adhere to (we were using TFS 2017 and VS2015). Now that we've moved to VSTS and VS2017 there is no way to enforce check-in policies. MS needs to add the original functionality back in, having the policy only apply within Visual Studio is pointless (in my opinion).

Comment: @msr Check-in policies have **always** functioned like that.